# what is the compatibility level of sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server

what is the compatibility level of sql server 2008 r2?

does anyone know when it will be released?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the compatibility is still the same in SQL Server 2008 R2 but you should take caution because the database internal version is bumped in R2. What does that mean to you? If you attach the database on a R2 server then you can't rollback or move back to SQL Server 2008 version.

http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/SQL-Server-2008-R2-bumps-the-database-version.aspx

If you don't know the difference between Compatibility and database version then you need to catch on the below post from Paul Randal.

http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Search-Engine-QA-13-Difference-between-database-version-and-database-compatibility-level.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's still 10- there have been minimal changes to the DB engine itself (mostly changes on the tooling side to support Sql Azure). Supposed to be out 1H 2010.

Answer (score 1):

The compatibility level is still 10.

There are no changes as far as I can see in T-SQL/DB-Engine.